# Positioning of the div using css when data is there and when data isnt there

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

i want to place a div at the end of the page when I am having no data and to place that same div after the content when I am having data.

Comment: What is the data? How are you obtaining it?

Comment: Please keep in mind that CSS may not be exactly what you're looking for doing this kind of operation. JavaScript may be used to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

To reorder the divs you can arrange the divs using angular flex layout and use fxFlexOrder property.

```
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div fxFlexOrder="4">1. One</div>
  <div fxFlexOrder="2">2. Two</div>
  <div fxFlexOrder="3">3. Three</div>
  <div fxFlexOrder="1">4. Four</div>
</div>
```

fxFlexOrder can be given as a dynamic value and changed based on your conditions

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlexOrder-API

Answer (score 0):

You can give initial css when data is not there and call a method when data is available where you can set the new css via javascript.

```
<div id="selectIt"  style="display: none">

</div>
```

Inside ts:

```
if(data){
const myelem = document.getElementById('selectIt');
   myelem.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an *ngIf="data" in the html element and position it using css.